# If an original post gives a misleading assumption in the question should it be edited?

Tags: discussion, editing, comments

I am writing some basic QGIS training notes and I came across this post [Is it possible to change the field length of a shapefile to over 254?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28226/is-it-possible-to-change-the-field-length-of-a-shapefile-to-over-255?rq=1)

However the maximum field length of a shapefile, I believe, is 254.

This based upon other GIS SE answers:

- [Maximum length of text fields in shapefile and geodatabase formats?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75092/maximimum-length-of-text-fields-in-shapefile-and-geodatabase-formats)
- [Does joining CSV file to shapefile overcomes the 255 character limitation of shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166473/does-joining-csv-file-to-shapefile-overcomes-the-255-character-limitation-of-sha?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and the Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Limitations

Should the original question be edited, a comment made, or the 254 limitation added to an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is to edit the question to correct it, and include a link to a reference that supports the 254 character limit.

Answer (score 4):

It depends if the misleading assumption is key information to solve OP's question, i.e., when correcting/responding to the misleading assumption is the answer (or significant part of the answer). In this case, don't edit the question, but answer it.

If the misleading assumption is marginal to what is being asked, I see no problem making a correction, which seems it was the case in the example you provided.